# model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'MainModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'testModel'

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, layout, partial-views, razor-pages

Any help will be appreciate!
I keep pages almost empty to first resolve this issue.
Tried different way in layout page to call partial view.
using asp.net core 2.1

My partial view for sure should load earlier than the main page. Now its empty, but it will contain some data to load.

This is my layout with single call to partial view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/PartialPages/test.cshtml");
                @*<partial name="~/Pages/PartialPages/test.cshtml" />*@
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    <div style="float: left; margin-left: 1%; width: 100%">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I have empty "Main" page

```
public class MainModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }

@page
@model APWeb.Pages.MainModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Main";
}

<h2>Main</h2>
```

This is my partial view page:

```
public class testModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }

@page
@model APWeb.Pages.PartialPages.testModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
```

My main page use layout page.[image]

Comment: After login I redirect into "Main"page, but Main page use Layout and Layout should load partial view. so the request is for Main page but partial view should be loaded before that, so I think this is the conflict, but dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a default model to your test.cshtml when initialize the Layout :

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Pages/PartialPages/test.cshtml",new testModel());
```

Comment: I fixed the issue with some changes and passing model, but I think yours would work as well. Thanks anyway,